# Is an rDNS PTR record really necessary to avoid spam filters?

Tags: nameserver, reverse-dns

I realize this is a somewhat abstract question, but does anyone have any experience with setting up an e-mail server without an rDNS record?

I ask because I really want to host my mail server at home, however my ISP doesn't support creating an rDNS for private customers.

So what I want to know is: How heavily does the rDNS check weigh in on spam checks?

So if everything else is in order, will my mails still be marked as spam simply because of a missing rDNS record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is an rDNS PTR record really necessary to avoid spam filters?

Yes.

---

Your provider may not support setting a *custom* PTR record but many providers do set *a* PTR record and associated A record in their domain for the ip-addresses they issue to customers.  E.g you may have been assigned `ran0m-lo0k1ng-hostnam3.dsl.customers.isp.example.com`

Simply ensure that your mail server identifies itself with that hostname and you should be good with regards to reverse DNS checks.

(**Note** Since mail servers can host mail for many different domains the hostname a mail server identifies itself with does not have to from the same domain as the sender email addresses in the messages transmitted by that mail server.)

Comment: That's a brilliant idea, however after re-checking unfortunately my static public IP doesn't have any rDNS PTR record set. So I'm outta luck.
Guess I'll have to opt for a VPS solution instead.

Comment: Then what does it validate? What good is it for the receiving mail service to know that the sender's IP belongs to *some* legit domain name, if the FROM points to something else entirely?